# Random characters when trying to randomize elements of an array

Tags: c, arrays, random

**This is Homework**

So for one of my projects, I have to make a game of scrabble. The main issue I have is when I randomize a set of 7 characters, I get 7 random symbols. A question mark with the prism behind it. I think this might be an issue with memory, but I have no clue on how to fix it. I'll have part of my program below:

```
 int arr[N];

const char let[] = 
{'K' , 'J' , 'X' , 'Q' , 'Z' , 'B' , 'C' , 'M' , 'P' , 'F' , 'H' , 'V' , 'W' , 'Y' , 'G' , 'L' , 'S' , 'U' , 'D' , 'N' , 'R' ,      'T' , 'O' , 'A' , 'I' , 'E'};

const int freq[] = 
{ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 8 , 9 , 9 , 12 };



        unsigned index = 0; 
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 26 ; i++) {
for(int f = 0 ; f < freq[i]; f++) {
        arr[index++] = let[i];  //All the 96 letters are stored in let[i]
            //printf("%c " , let[i]);  // Created the letter bank for all the letters 

} }
           int letter = 0;
        printf("Your letters are: ");
    for(int l = 0; l < 7; l++){
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

         letter = rand() % 96; 
                printf("%c  ", let[letter]); }
```

So in a game of scrabble each letter has different frequencies. That's what the freq array is used for. There are 96 total possible characters for a game of scrabble and all those letters are stored in the array let[i]. So for my randomizer that starts from "int letter = 0), I have a loop to make it so the user will get 7 letters back. I have mod 96 because that's how many possible letters there are in a game of scrabble. The issue is the print statement at the end is just giving me random characters. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @xing wow thanks that worked. The printf statement just gave me the same letter 7 times. Ill figure that part out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why did calling srand further up on the code fix the whole thing?